# Angular select option send value id only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I try to use ngOptions Angular. I want to send parameter to back-end to send value only not object.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Parent Menu</label>
  <select class="form-control" ng-model="admin_asset.parent_id" ng-options="parent.title for parent in parent_asset_options">
    <option value="">-- choose parent --</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

When I select the option, the output shows:

```
"parent_id": {
  "id": 1,
  "title": "Index Assets"
}
```

I just want to send value `1` only. So the result should be:

```
"parent_id": 1
```

I have tried to another tutorial but I did not have solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `select as`

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Parent Menu</label>
  <select class="form-control" ng-model="admin_asset.parent_id" ng-options="parent.id as parent.title for parent in parent_asset_options">
    <option value="">-- choose parent --</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's necessary to extend you `ng-options` expression with some extra fields.

`ng-options="parent.id as parent.title for parent in parent_asset_options"`

[more examples](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)